# Piecewise Linear Function as Constraint

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pyscipopt

I'm trying to use pyscipopt to solve a linear programming problem, but am unable to fit the piecewise linear function as a constraint.

The constraint is expressed as follows:

[image: Constraint]

I've tried to write it as the following:

`cfm = quicksum( max(quicksum(cf[i][t] * q[i] - L[t] for i in range(I)), 0) for t in range(T) /  quicksum(L[t] for t in range(T)) <= cfm_max`

Where cfm_max = 0.15, in this case.

But it is probably very wrong since it returns a `NotImplementedError`. I've seen examples in `piecewise.py` found together with the package, but their usage seems different enough to not work in my case.

Would appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be written as:

```
sum(t,y[t]) <= 0.15*sum(t,L[t])
y[t] >= sum(i,CF[i,t]*q[i])-L[t]
```

where `y[t]` are non-negative variables. This is now completely linear (no division, no max()).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. But `y[t]` has to be able to take on negative values (just due to the field of this problem). It is `sum(y[t]|y[t]>0)/L[t]` that has to be less than 0.15. The constraints proposed would be a feasible, but far from optimal solution.

Comment: No.  `max(...,0)` can never assume negative values. By definition. Check your math.

Comment: I think I understand what you are doing now, and the optimization seems to be working. Many thanks.